# Appending and updating DB2 table rows in R object using ibmdbR package

Tags: r, db2

I've got a data.table DT that I'd like to write to DB2 and update using ibmdbR package.

I upload the first batch using as.ida.data.frame.

```
> DT<- data.table(A = c(111,222,333,444), MONTH= c('2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04'), B= c(11,22,33,44))
> DT
     A   MONTH  B
1: 111 2018-01 11
2: 222 2018-02 22
3: 333 2018-03 33
4: 444 2018-04 44

> db2_test <- as.ida.data.frame(DT, table='myschema.TEST', clear.existing=FALSE, case.sensitive=FALSE,
                  rownames=NULL, dbname='DB_NAME', asAOT=FALSE)
```

This creates a DB2 table named TEST in my schema in the database.
Then I try to update TEST based on column MONTH using another data.table DT2 by doing:

```
> DT2 <- data.table(A = c(999,888), MONTH = c('2018-01', '2019-02'), B = c(99,77))
> DT2
     A   MONTH  B
1: 999 2018-01 99
2: 888 2019-02 77

> idaUpdate(myconnection, updf = 'myschema.TEST', dfrm = DT2, idaIndex = 'MONTH')
Error in sqlUpdate(db2Conn, dfrm, updf, index = idaIndex, fast = ifelse(idaIsOracleMode(),  : 
  [RODBC] Failed exec in Update02000 100 [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000
```

While i receive this error, when I look at the data in TEST table in DB2 database, the first entry has changed, which is expected.

```
A    MONTH  B
999 2018-01 99
222 2018-02 22
333 2018-03 33
444 2018-04 44
```

So i think the error comes from the second entry in DT2. there are no rows in TEST with MONTH = '2019-02', so it fails.
But I thought the point of updating with an index column is substituting the rows that have a match with the index column and adding the rows that don't?

How can I update TEST properly with DT2, so that if month exists then update the rows? but add the news ones if there are no rows in TEST that match MONTH column in DT2?

basically, how can I append data properly to a DB2 table from an R object?
I never had issues with AWS. DB2 is a nightmare.

Comment: idaUpdate is a wrapper for sqlUpdate, which requires that the rows already exist , as stated in the Rdocumentation. Thus the warning SQLCODE 100 is functionally correct if you are trying to update a non-existent row. Check if other methods are more appropriate.

Comment: idaAppend() function only appends. It doesn't update. sqlUpdate only updates one row at a time. How can a row be updated (replaced) by multiple rows? My question could be extended to a specific a case when one row (say row with month = '2018-01' in TEST table needs to be replaced by two rows in DT2 which  have month = '2018-01'.